# How to show multiple Date/Times per location?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

1. Using Google Spreadsheets, I need to enter data structured like the example below.

   - There will be multiple "quadrants"
   - Each "quadrant" can contain *one or many* "days",
   - Each "day" can contain *one or many* "times".
2. This data will ultimately be imported in some backend db (e.g. Access DB, SQL, MySQL).
3. **Question**: *For each day*, how do I represent multiple times? Do I create a new row?

**Quadrant One Team Schedules**

- **Sunday**

  - 10:00 AM  - Red Team
  - 3:00 PM   - Green Team
- **Monday**

  - 6:00 AM   - Red Team
  - 10:00 AM  - Yellow Team
  - 3:30 PM   - Green Team
- **Tuesday**
- **Wednesday**

  - 6:00 PM - Yellow Team
- **Thursday**

  - 1:00 PM - Red Team
- **Friday**
- **Saturday**

  - 10:00 AM - Blue Team
  - 3:00 PM  - Red Team

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not quite sure what answer you are expecting but wanting to post an image (and probably length!) is why this is not a comment.

Poor data layout that requires changes to help legibility or changes to facilitate further processing is, IMO, a very big issue – much more so than, it seems, is appreciated by novices (see perhaps [Kruger-Dunning](http://www.jerwood-no.org.uk/pdf/Dunning%20Kruger.pdf)). Again merely my opinion, but I think about half of all questions on SO have data layout as an issue, in whole or part.

Some suggestions:

1. With databases, always have an index (ID) to identify unique records (rows). Often added automatically.
2. Try to ensure each record is complete for every field (nulls may cause issues). ID6 seems not required.
3. Use dates rather than days of the week (it is easier to get the day from the date than the date from the day!)
4. (Personal preference – not always viable) Use ‘scientific’ notation for dates (YYYYMMDD) to avoid ambiguity between ‘US’ and ‘UK’ systems – and the difficulties in switching between them.
5. Use the 24-hour clock (saves the space for `AM` and `PM`, reduces ambiguity and generally is easier to process).
6. Not so important nowadays but should consider codes (with a lookup table if desired) such as `YL` for `Yellow` rather than indeterminate length strings – saves on data storage so less cost, more speed win/win.

[image: SO30554211 example]

Comment: What an "interesting" answer. So it appears (from your image) that yes, I need to simply add a new row. However, my larger issue is that of "further processing" as you put it. True, I need to export the  spreadsheet data into an XML file and was concerned about not duplicating content (like the Day field does).  As for the whole Kruger-Dunning thing, may I quote Shakespeare? "The Fool doth think he is wise, but the wise man knows himself to be a Fool". So.. you know... there's that. Thank you for your comments.